# OS-related strtr issue

Tags: php, case-sensitive, strtr

I have this function that converts all special chars to uppercase:

```
function uc_latin1($str) {
    if(!defined("LATIN1_UC_CHARS"))
        define("LATIN1_UC_CHARS", "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ");
    if(!defined("LATIN1_LC_CHARS"))
        define("LATIN1_LC_CHARS", "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý");
    $str = strtoupper ( strtr ( $str, LATIN1_LC_CHARS, LATIN1_UC_CHARS ) );
    return $str;
}
```

This function works fine in my development PC which runs Windows XP... but, when I test it in the production server running Red Hat Linux, it does not uppercase the string. The string is ISO-8859-1 encoded.

How can I make it work in Linux too?

Comment: Which part doesn't work: the `strtr()` or the `strtoupper()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [mb_strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)? On my computer, this converts, at least, all of the characters you have defined although it may undesirably convert others as well.

For example:

```
$str = àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý;
$str = mb_strtoupper($str);
echo $str;
// Prints ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in both Linux and Windows. Thank you so much.